# Why is the element of array (string[] ) inferred as undefined?

Tags: typescript

Here is function called checkMultipleImgs returning array filed with string. (string[])

```
  const checkMultipleImgs = async (fileName: string): Promise<string[]> => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('fitting').list('', {
      offset: 0,
      sortBy: { column: 'name', order: 'asc' },
      search: fileName,
    });

    return data ? data.map((item) => item.name) : [];
  };
```

And there's this variable "newUrls" which is the return value of checkMultipleImgs function (string[])

```
      const newUrls = await checkMultipleImgs(fileName);
      if (newUrls && newUrls.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < newUrls.length; i++) {
          const newFileName = newUrls[i];
          const url = await getImgUrl(newFileName);
          if (url) {
            urls.push(url);
          }
        }
      }
```

But.. why do I get this error?

It's saying newUrls[i] can be string | undefined.
I don't know why undefined is inferred here.

[image]

Comment: If you hover over the variable `newUrls` where you declare it, what does VS Code say about its type?

Comment: @StefanoLeone it said string[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's 'noUncheckedIndexedAccess' in TS, which adds 'undefined' as a return type for arrays.

```js
const myFunc = (s: string) => console.log(s);
const myArr = ['test', 'array'];

myFunc(myArr[0]) // <-- the warning
```

Potentially solve with forEach, avoiding the index lookup

```js
const myFunc = (s: string) => console.log(s);
const myArr = ['test', 'array'];

myArr.forEach(myFunc)

// or 

myArr.forEach((myVal) => {
  // do things with the string
})
```

or assert that it's not undefined.

Comment: Oh you were right. The error disappear when I set "noUncheckedIndexedAccess" false. After reading about 'noUncheckedIndexecAccess' (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess), I was curious again why it is inferred as undefined although I wrote "newUrls" are string[]? Then I figured out that it's because it can't guarantee that newUrls[i] is defined.... Thank you for letting me know this option!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking `newUrls` array from a promise, it also has a possiblity to get rejected and the value can also be `undefined`. So, with the same reason typescript infers that you `newUrls[i]` variable can also have an `undefined` value.

Solution for this is to apply a type for the value while assignment.

```
const newFileName = newUrls[i] as string;
```

This should solve the type-error you're getting.

Comment: When a promise gets rejected it throws an error, you don't get undefined as a result.

Comment: I get same error even when I declare "newFileName" type directly as string[]. It seems like "noUncheckedIndexedAccess" is the reason.